# can anyone tell me what is the time complexity of the code below:

Tags: python, for-loop, time-complexity

I am trying to find an index value in 2D array and I don't know about time complexity of this code

```py
for i in matrix:
    if target in i: print("yes")
```

Comment: It looks like in the worst case the code will look at every element of matrix, so it's O(N) where N is the number of elements in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

O(nm) ; n x m is the dimension of the matrix

Comment: This answer is perfectly correct, and the comment above is misguided.